# Hibernate only loads one object of query-collection

Tags: java, sql-server, hibernate

A few days ago I've encountered a strange behaviour in Hibernate and can't say why it appeared out of the sudden.

There are two tables sharing an unidirectional 1:n relation. There is the record-catalog which contains *n* records. Under conditions I am not able to spot only one record is loaded. No error-messages occurred. No warnings either.

Actually it's pretty easy stuff, always used to work. (Code for the objects in the end of this posting)

Till now I can only say if the Record-Catalog has the ID 78 only one record will be loaded. For the other IDs it appears to be fine.

I'm fetching my RC-Object like that:

```
public String getCatalog(){
Session session = null;

    try {

        SessionFactory factory = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory();
        session = factory.openSession();
        Transaction tx = session.beginTransaction();
        String hql = "SELECT R FROM rcatalog.Rcatalog as R WHERE rcatalogID_PK = " + rcid;
        Query query = session.createQuery(hql);
        return getOutputForPage(query.list().get(0)); //If I get the size of the records it's 1 here

    } catch (HibernateException | java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException hibex) {
        Logger.getLogger(BasisHibernate.class.getName()).log(Level.INFO, "Rcid: {0}", rcid);
        Logger.getLogger(BasisHibernate.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, hibex);
    } finally {
        try {
            if (session != null) {
                session.close();
            }
        } catch (HibernateException | NullPointerException hibex) {
        }
    }
    return "";
}
```

So far this seems alright for me. The ID is the correct one. I decided to switch the sql-output on and get the following line 
(M_ID --> ID for the Catalog
D_ID --> ID for the Record
):

> ```
> Hibernate: select myrecord0_.M_ID as M65_9_1_, myrecord0_.D_ID as D1_1_, myrecord0_.D_ID as D1_7_0_ from [MyProj].[dbo].[MyRecord] myrecord0_ where myrecord0_.M_ID=?
> ```

By using the query in the SQL Server Management Studio I get the amount of records listed as expected.

Till now I have tried to delete the single record which appears but the behaviour keeps the same.

I did some research already but haven't been too successful:

- [Hibernate only loads one object from a list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8260064/hibernate-only-loads-one-object-from-a-list)
- - Entirely different error
- http://www.coderanch.com/t/442282/ORM/databases/Hibernate-loads-element-collection
- - I don't think we have the same problem
- [Hibernate manyToMany only returns one element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24121020/hibernate-manytomany-only-returns-one-element)
- - No restrictions used
- http://www.laliluna.de/jpa-hibernate-guide/ch02s02.html
- - Interesting article but I have tried switching lazy to eager, was restarting my servers, rebuilding the project. Still the same

Here are my classes (As stated before, I'm not using FetchType.EAGER. This was for test-purposes only)

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "[MyProj].[dbo].[Rcatalog]")
public class Rcatalog implements Serializable {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
@Column(name = "M_ID")
private Integer RcatalogID_PK;

@ManyToOne()
@JoinColumn(name = "W_ID", insertable = false, updatable = false)
private UpperElement upperelement;

@Column(name = "W_ID")
@JoinColumn(name = "upperelementID_FK", referencedColumnName = "upperelementID_PK")
private Integer upperelementID_FK;

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "myrecordID_FK", fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@Sort(type = SortType.COMPARATOR, comparator = MyRecordComparator.class)
private SortedSet<MyRecord> myrecord = new TreeSet<>();

//Constructor, Getter, Setter...
}
```

And there are the records:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "[MyProj].[dbo].[MyRecord]")
public class MyRecord implements Serializable, PartElementInterface {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
@Column(name = "D_ID")
private Integer myrecordID_PK;

@Column(name = "M_ID")
@JoinColumn(name = "myrecordID_FK", referencedColumnName = "myrecordID_PK")
private Integer myrecordID_FK;

@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "M_ID", insertable = false, updatable = false, nullable = true)
private Rcatalog rcatalog;

//Constructor, Getter, Setter and some more stuff
}
```

My Hibernate-core version is 3.6.10.Final

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer myself:

We have the following comparator here:

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "myrecordID_FK", fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@Sort(type = SortType.COMPARATOR, comparator = MyRecordComparator.class)
private SortedSet<MyRecord> myrecord = new TreeSet<>();
```

With a simple compare-algorithm:

public class MyRecordComparator implements Comparator{

```
@Override
public int compare(Object obj1, Object obj2) {
    MyRecord d1 = (MyRecord) obj1;
    MyRecord d2 = (MyRecord) obj2;

    return d1.getPos_nr().compareTo(d2.getPos_nr());
    }

}
```

After running some tests I figured out my records are only successfully loaded if the compare-method returns -1 or 1. If both compare-values are equal and the return-value is 0 we're getting problems with the `SortedSet`.

So I changed it to:

public class MyRecordComparator implements Comparator{

```
@Override
public int compare(Object obj1, Object obj2) {
    MyRecord d1 = (MyRecord) obj1;
    MyRecord d2 = (MyRecord) obj2;

    int c1 = d1.getPos_nr().compareTo(d2.getPos_nr());

    if (c1 == 0) {
        int c2 = d1.getAltval().compareTo(d2.getAltval());

        return (c2 == 0) ? 1 : c2;

    } else {
        return c1;
    }
}

}
```